Is essential flutter home widget for working some feature of my app is okey for user experiance?
I'm trying to make a flutter project and I won't go into details, but I have an issue where some feature of my app can only work in real-time, which means installing the necessary home widget for this feature to work. Is this normal for the user? Potentially, I can't use background tasks because I want to take a screenshot of the current state of some  widget recurrently (every 10 seconds) that changes its state every 10 seconds.
